# Disable button with button selector

Tags: android, android-button, android-selector

I have a button selector that changes the button image when it is pressed. I have also set an image for when the button is disabled. I try and disable the button programmatically but the disabled button image is not appearing. Is my button_selector correct?

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_bg_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/> <!-- disabled -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_bg_pressed" android:state_focused="true"/> <!-- focused -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_bg"/> <!-- default -->
```

I am using mButton.setEnabled(false) in my code to disable the button

Answer (score 42, accepted):

try this one and i uploaded one sample project for you for more help check the project

selector.xml

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_disable" android:state_enabled="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>

    </selector>
```

and use this selector in button as following

```
<Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector"
         android:enabled="false"
         android:text="Disable Button" />
```

sample code link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lydkog10rkujbsa/ButtonSelector.rar

Comment: Working like a charm! "enabled" helped me alot

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/> <!-- pressed -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_bg_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/> <!-- disabled -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_btn_bg"/> <!-- default -->
```