# TextView clickable not working in xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i do *TextView* UnClickable. ? When I tried with `android:clickable="false"` but, it doesn't working for me.

See below `XML` code :

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv_submit"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height_common"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
   android:background="@drawable/back_btn_yellow_rounded"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:alpha="0.50"
   android:clickable="false" <!--Hear you can see i set clickable="false-->
   android:textSize="@dimen/btn_label_inputtextsize"
   android:text="@string/submit"
   android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_bold"/>
```

### Update:

Initialization of `Checkbox` :

```
        chk_credit_card =  findViewById(R.id.chk_credit_card);
        chk_debit_card = findViewById(R.id.chk_debit_card);
        chk_bank_deposit = findViewById(R.id.chk_bank_deposit);
        chk_in_app_purchase = findViewById(R.id.chk_in_app_purchase);
```

Work with checkbox code:

```
for (CheckBox checkBox : chk_credit_card) {
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @SuppressLint("Range")
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        // one of the checkbox is checked so enable button
                        tv_submit.setEnabled(true);
                        tv_submit.setAlpha(150);
                        tv_submit.setEnabled(true);
                       /* chk_debit_card.setChecked(false);
                        chk_bank_deposit.setChecked(false);
                        chk_in_app_purchase.setChecked(false);*/
                    } else {
                        // check if any of check box is checked
                        boolean isAnyChecked = false;
                        for (CheckBox box : chk_credit_card) {
                            if (box.isChecked()) isAnyChecked = true;
                        }
                        tv_submit.setEnabled(isAnyChecked);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I refer too much solution but it's not working for me. So please help. :)

Comment: What is your purpose?

Comment: textview is not clickable by default

Comment: post some more details....

Comment: i'll set the `OnClickListener` of this `textview` for  moving a one activity to another activity. my purpose is if i select the `checkbox` then it's show me as a `clickable` other wise not. @Khemraj

Comment: @SandeepPatel They downvote you because your question is not complete.

Comment: then please inform me i'll provide other info if you not getting my question @jackjay

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: @SandeepPatel you never mentioned in your question about checkbox. You should always post your complete question along with related scenarios.

Comment: okay thank you @jackjay next time i'll post my question with full detail. again thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                    // do your work
                }
            }
        });
```

**Update**

- You have multiple checkbox
- If any of checkbox is checked then button should be enabled
- Checkbox should be listened live.

  ```
  ArrayList<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
  checkBoxes.add(checkBox1);
  checkBoxes.add(checkBox2); // add all your checkbox
  for (CheckBox checkBox : checkBoxes) {
      checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked) {
                  // one of the checkbox is checked so enable button
                  textView.setEnabled(true);
              } else {
                  // check if any of check box is checked
                  boolean isAnyChecked = false;
                  for (CheckBox box : checkBoxes) {
                      if (box.isChecked()) isAnyChecked = true;
                  }
                  textView.setEnabled(isAnyChecked);
              }
          }
      });
  }
  ```

**Suggestion**

TextView has no ripple effect by default, use Button for a good UI. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18517673/6891563) for making background selector for enabled, disabled, pressed colors.

#### Update 2

After looking into your problem, you actually need `RadioGroup`, that allow to check only one `RadioButton`

```
if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){
  // no radio button is checked
} 
else {
  // one radio button is checked
}
```

Just use RadioGroup in your xml. Here is an example.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@id/rbMale"
    >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbMale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Male"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbFemale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```

You can do `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rbMale` also.

#### Update 3

If you want CheckBox like RadioButton, its very easy

```
<RadioButton
    style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
    ...
    />
```

**Contrats!, all  your problem solved :)**

Comment: hear i have 4 checkbox. if i select anyone then and then it's show me a TextView Clickable otherwise not.

Comment: If you use data binding, I can tell you one line solution.

Comment: no i'm not use data binding. and i'll use your code and i replaced `checkBoxes`  with  my checkbox id `chk_credit_card` then give me a this error `foreach not applicable to type 'android.widget.CheckBox`

Comment: yeas i'll check wait.

Comment: now it's give me a error on initialization **`error: incompatible types: no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds CheckBox[],View
where T is a type-variable:
T extends View declared in method <T>findViewById(int)`**

Comment: it's working brother. but it's a multiple selection i don't want to do multiple selection :(

Comment: What mean multiple selection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181726/discussion-between-sandeep-patel-and-khemraj).

Comment: You want other checkboxes uncheck when an checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 3):

Try This,
In Android Studio Package List There is a folder called 'res'
under the 'res' folder select folder called values select styles.xml in given folder

Change it values from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To This

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Hope it Works!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this property to your `TextView` to make it not clickable

From your XML

```
android:enabled="false"
```

In JAVA

```
             textView.setEnabled(checkBox.isChecked());
```

Comment: @SRBbans what do you mean by this ?

Comment: This answer can be shortened to `textView.setEnabled(checkbox.isChecked())` :)

Answer (score 0):

**As per your comment...** you can follow this logic.

```
textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (if_checked) {
                    // go to another activity             
                }else{
                   //ignore
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

setting onClickListener to TextView will change clickable property to true. If you don't want to textView clicked do not set it clickListener.
If you want to textView will be clickable on some cases and don't want to other cases then you can set click listener or remove it like:

**to enable clicks:**

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //do your work
            }
        });
```

**to disable clicks:**

```
textView.setOnClickListener(null);
```